# Find and Replace in a Large File

Tags: powershell

I want to find a piece of text in a large xml file and want to replace with some other text. The size of the file is around (50GB). I want to do this in command line. I am looking at PowerShell and want to know if it can handle the large size.

Currently I am trying something like this but it does not like it

```
Get-Content C:\File1.xml | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "xmlns:xsi=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\"", ""} | Set-Content C:\File1.xml
```

The text I want to replace is  `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` with an empty string `""`.

Questions

1. Can PowerShell handle large
   files
2. I don't want the replace to happen in
   memory and prefer streaming assuming
   that will not bring the server to
   its knees.
3. Are there any other approaches I can take (different
   tools/strategy?)

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar need (and similar lack of powershell experience) but cobbled together a complete answer from the other answers on this page plus a bit more research.

I also wanted to avoid the regex processing, since I didn't need it either -- just a simple string replace -- but on a large file, so I didn't want it loaded into memory.

Here's the command I used (adding linebreaks for readability):

```
Get-Content sourcefile.txt
    | Foreach-Object {$_.Replace('http://example.com', 'http://another.example.com')}
    | Set-Content result.txt
```

Worked perfectly!  Never sucked up much memory (it very obviously didn't load the whole file into memory), and just chugged along for a few minutes then finished.

Comment: on a 200 MB file PS took 3.5 GB RAM. 30%CPU when I killed it.

Comment: maybe check **-ReadCount** or **-RAW**  http://www.happysysadm.com/2014/10/reading-large-text-files-with-powershell.html

Answer (score 14):

Aside from worrying about reading the file in chunks to avoid loading it into memory, you need to dump to disk often enough that you aren't storing the entire contents of the resulting file in memory.

```
Get-Content sourcefile.txt -ReadCount 10000 | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $line = $_.Replace('http://example.com', 'http://another.example.com')
        Add-Content -Path result.txt -Value $line
    }
```

The `-ReadCount <number>` sets the number of lines to read at a time. Then the `ForEach-Object` writes each line as it is read. For a 30GB file filled with SQL Inserts, I topped out around 200MB of memory and 8% CPU. While, piping it all into `Set-Content` at hit 3GB of memory before I killed it.

Comment: Given the default of readcount as 1, is this actually an improvement? Certain files contain everything on one line (such as minimized json).

Comment: @duct_tape_coder I feel like that would depend on how fast the up speed was. I'll do some tests and update the answer if removing/changing the read count has a better  effect. I'm also going to look into some other options I've been made aware of since I posted this answer.

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer , thanks

Comment: This is super fast. I had a one-off scenario involving a 1.1-million line file that crashed NotePad++ and other Ps scripts. This ran in seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It does not like it because you can't read from a file and write back to it at the same time using Get-Content/Set-Content.  I recommend using a temp file and then at the end, rename file1.xml to file1.xml.bak and rename the temp file to file1.xml.

1. Yes as long as you don't try to load the whole file at once.  Line-by-line will work but is going to be a bit slow.  Use the -ReadCount parameter and set it to 1000 to improve performance.
2. Which command line?  PowerShell?  If so then you can invoke your script like so `.\myscript.ps1` and if it takes parameters then `c:\users\joe\myscript.ps1 c:\temp\file1.xml`.
3. In general for regexes I would use single quotes if you don't need to reference PowerShell variables.  Then you only need to worry about regex escaping and not PowerShell escaping as well.  If you need to use double-quotes then the back-tick character is the escape char in double-quotes e.g. "`$p1 is set to $ps1".  In your example single quoting simplifies your regex to (note: forward slashes aren't metacharacters in regex):

   'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'
4. Absolutely you want to stream this since 50GB won't fit into memory.  However, this poses an issue if you process line-by-line.  What if the text you want to replace is split across multiple lines?
5. If you don't have the split line issue then I think PowerShell can handle this.

Comment: @Keith, you really trust PowerShell ;) I would maybe worry about OutOfMemoryException because 50gb is large enough to collect little memory leaks.. just a guess. Personally I would use directly `File.Open` and work with a stream and compare manually (no regex).

Comment: And shouldn't one use some sort of XML API to do this? Just a thought. Dunno if SAX or StAX are available in .NET; I work too rarely with XML, but doing a string replace sounds wrong for this.

Comment: .NET has a forward-only, cursor style reader (XmlReader/XmlTextReader) - a pull mechanism which is a bit different than the SAX push approach.  It's a bit tedious but a good way to go when the whole Xml document won't fit into memory.

Comment: @stej, good point on the regex - doesn't look it is required and coudl be replaced by a String.Replace().

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on it, building on some of the other answers here:

```
Function ReplaceTextIn-File{
  Param(
    $infile,
    $outfile,
    $find,
    $replace
  )

  if( -Not $outfile)
  {
    $outfile = $infile
  }

  $temp_out_file = "$outfile.temp"

  Get-Content $infile | Foreach-Object {$_.Replace($find, $replace)} | Set-Content $temp_out_file

  if( Test-Path $outfile)
  {
    Remove-Item $outfile
  }

  Move-Item $temp_out_file $outfile
}
```

And called like so:

```
ReplaceTextIn-File -infile "c:\input.txt" -find 'http://example.com' -replace 'http://another.example.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of the answer from @Digital_Coyote to add a buffer. During testing using the buffer increased the RAM usage to ~700MB at times (with 1000 row buffer, this usage will vary based on the size of each row in your file) but sped up the processing significantly testing with a 500MB file. You can adjust the `$flushCnt` value which represents the number of rows to buffer before writing them to the file. The smaller the `$flushCnt`, the less RAM the process will use.

As mentioned by others, piping directly to `Set-Content` used a huge amount of RAM for very large files, so that is why I'm using a buffer instead.

```
$sourceFile = 'J:\BacPacs\model.raw.xml'
$destinationFile = 'J:\BacPacs\model.replaced.xml'
$flushCnt = 1000;
$searchForString = '<Property Name="AutoDrop" Value="True" />';
$replaceWithString = '';

$buffer = @();
$buffCnt = 0;
Get-Content -LiteralPath $sourceFile -ReadCount 1000 | %{
    $buffer += $_.Replace($searchForString,$replaceWithString);
    $buffCnt++;
    if($buffCnt -ge $flushCnt)
    {
        $buffer | Add-Content -LiteralPath $destinationFile
        $buffer = @();
        $buffCnt = 0;
    }
} 
#flush anything still remaining in the buffer
if($buffCnt -gt 0)
{
    $buffer | Add-Content -LiteralPath $destinationFile
    $buffer = @();
    $buffCnt = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The escape character in powershell strings is the backtick ( ` ), not backslash ( \ ). I'd give an example, but the backtick is also used by the wiki markup. :(

The only thing you should have to escape is the quotes - the periods and such should be fine without.